# Is there a to check how many users using compact/comfy display density view?

Tags: lightning, soql, profile, user, view

Goal is to find out all users in the org using Compact/Comfy density View. Is there a way to figure it out via SOQL query or Report?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query against the [UserPreference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userpreference.htm) object. Looking at the doc, you can see that density is stored as 108 in the `Preference` field and has been included since API 44. You can include `tolabel(Preference)` in your query to get the setting name as well.

[image]

The [Theme](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_theme.htm) documentation mentions the two values for density that correlate to the following

- ViewOne -  Comfy
- ViewTwo - Compact

**Query to get density settings**

```
SELECT Id,tolabel(Preference),SystemModstamp,UserId,Value FROM UserPreference WHERE Preference = '108'
```

The value will contain whether it's comfy or compact. They're displayed as `VIEW_ONE` vs. `VIEW_TWO` and a UserId can be returned as well.

**Query to get User information as well as their density settings they've set**

The User object is the parent and the relationship name is "UserPreferences". You'll see some active users do not have a preference and I believe they are just the value of whatever your org "Density settings" defaults are.

```
SELECT Name,isActive,Profile.Name, (SELECT Value FROM UserPreferences WHERE Preference = '108') FROM User WHERE isActive = true AND UserType = 'Standard'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. this is helpful

Comment: One this I have observed if want to know User's name and if in query I use User.Name instead of UserId, it throws an error

Comment: I added a different query using User and a subquery on UserPreferences that you can use as well.